# Adobe flash cs6 Output window closes automatically while executing Filesteam operation in .exe file but it works fine in flash debug mode

Tags: actionscript-3, air, flash-cs6, flashdevelop

I am using **adobe flash cs6** for creating a desktop application. In that application iam using ***flash.filesystem.filestream*** to save a text file
(I dont want to use ***FileReference*** because I don't want show the save dialog box )
When I call the new FileStream() in the exported ***.swf*** or ***.exe*** file, the app stopped running and it closes the window.
here is my sample code while executing this line 
**var fileStream : FileStream = new FileStream();**
the window closed automatically but this code work fine in Preview mode 
( ctrl + Enter) iam using 
Target: AIR 2.5; 
Script: ActionScript 3.0
in publish settings.

*sample.as*

```
package{
import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;    

public class SampleClass {
    public function generateReport (text : String) : void
    { 
        var fileMode:String = (FileMode.APPEND);
        var fileStream : FileStream = new FileStream();
        var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("sample.txt");
        fileStream.open (file, fileMode);
        fileStream.writeMultiByte (text, File.systemCharset);
        fileStream.close ();
    }

}
```

}

Is there any way to solve this problem ? 
Thank you very much!

Pravin

Comment: Got any (minimal) testable code of your setup? Easier to test same code ourselves to advise. Does it work if **.exe** is opened using _"run as Admin"_ option? Sounds like a permissions issue of some kind. PS: Also you can update to latest AIR SDK even in older CS6.

Comment: No, It does n't works if i opened my .exe file using "Run as admin"

Comment: update your Air to at least air 3.0, also make sure creating exe with publish button.

Comment: I tested your code. The exe **did not crash or close** for me but also it did not create a text file on Desktop (the Debugger test worked fine as same for you). I think your problem is this line : `.writeMultiByte (text, File.systemCharset);` once it was changed, the exe made a text file. I'll expand this into an Answer soon. Why `File.systemCharset`? Are you writing non-English alpahabet characters?

Comment: No, i have appended only English alphabets and a special symbol comma i have tested by commenting all my line except `var fileStream : FileStream = new FileStream();`. while executing this line my window gets closed while running .exe file but in debugger mode it works fine. i think i have missed something while publishing.

Comment: Iam using Script: Action script 3.0 and target: AIR sdk 25.0.0.134 for desktop, I have uploaded my *publish settings* snap in the below link


1. [Publish setting link 1](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-vA1r4nxL2TSmszYTZlUXdMSTA)
2. [Publish settings link 2](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B-vA1r4nxL2TVWR6OW9ac1cweWM)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea what content of `text` is, but from that `.writeMultiByte (text, File.systemCharset);` I assume you wanted to write non-English alphabetic chars?

Best just use `.writeUTFBytes` since that handles both English & foreign alphabets.

Anycase... See if this code re-fix `SampleClass.as` works for you (tested with no crashing **.exe**) :

```
package{

import flash.filesystem.File;
import flash.filesystem.FileStream;
import flash.filesystem.FileMode;

import flash.display.MovieClip;

public class SampleClass extends MovieClip {

    public function SampleClass ()
    {
        generateReport("test Chinese : 你好 世界 ... test Urdu : ہیلو دنیا ... test Russian : Привет мир");
    }

    public function generateReport (text : String) : void
    { 
        var fileMode:String = "append"; //not... String = (FileMode.APPEND);
        var fileStream : FileStream = new FileStream();
        var file:File = File.desktopDirectory.resolvePath("sample.txt");

        fileStream.open (file, fileMode);
        //fileStream.writeMultiByte (text, File.systemCharset); //trying non-English chars??
        fileStream.writeUTFBytes(text); //UTF is Unicode so can handle non-English chars
        fileStream.close();
        //trace("Text Done... check file \"sample.txt\" in Desktop");
    }

} //end Class
} //end Package
```

Comment: PS: The foreign chars showed fine even with basic **Notepad** tool. Let me know if any issues with "gibberish" chars if opened elsewhere.

Comment: I have replaced my code with the above one its working fine while debugging and text file was generated  with the text ( test Chinese : 你好 世界 ... test Urdu : ہیلو دنیا ... test Russian : Привет мир ) but while publishing to .exe file my window gets closed. while creating a object for SampleClass `var mainReport:SampleClass = new SampleClass();` ; Is there any way to solve this problem ? i have changed my sdk versions and still there is no improvement .The same problem was repeating.

Comment: if you remove `mainReport:SampleClass = new SampleClass();` the program is running normally?

Comment: @pravin I saw you were [making a **projector**](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-vA1r4nxL2TVWR6OW9ac1cweWM/view) (an SWF wrapped as EXE file)? To use `FileStream` class you must export a real Windows application (via AIR). If you are not being asked for an _install path_ when you first run the EXE (or your app does not show in Control Panel under _Programs_) then you did it wrong. Didn't have time to update with screen grabs of process but [**this link**](http://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/flash/how-to-publish-an-air-application-in-adobe-flash-cs6/) will help you.

Comment: Basically after you selected "Air for Desktop" click the wrench icon next to **Target**. Select "EXE installer" and hit **Publish**. If too much problems about timestamps etc, then choose instead to _Use a certificate_. To create one just click "Create Certificate" button (Flash makes it automatically, but you just give easy testing password to later re-use same certificate file even on other projects.. eg: use p-word:  _pravin_ ). Ask anything if my rambling didn't make sense.

Comment: Yeah  it's working fine thanks a lot  Valerio Charles. File was created without any error.