# Creating a cross platform runtime AIR app

Tags: actionscript-3, air, animate-cc

I am compiling an AIR application from Animate CC (mac version) with runtime embedded. No issues on the mac, but when i transfer the app file to a PC (running windows obviously), the app icon displays as a folder instead, and there is nothing within this folder that I can click on to run the app.

I was under the impression that Adobe AIR is cross platform compatible, so am I doing something wrong when compiling, or do I have to compile on a PC to create a runtime embedded app that will run on Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to launch Mac app on Windows. Because embed runtimes are different for Win/Mac. Here you can get some more info https://superuser.com/questions/56739/executable-files-in-mac-os-x-vs-windows.

So you either build 'Mac projector' and run it on Mac or 'Windows projector' to run on Windows (you can change this option in File -> Publish Settings). Tick both options and you'll be able to run it on Win and Mac.

One more option is to build AIR app - but it will require AIR runtime installed.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Unfortunately I need to write to a file that will be located locally on the machine, and I need to use the FileStream class so it can write to the file in the background without bringing up an alert. The FileStream class can only be accessed with AIR and not a projector, but I guess it is what it is. Thank you for clarifying.

Comment: @user1391152 see my last two comments  at bottom of this [**Answer**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/43079318/2057709). Instead of a projector just output a real Windows `.EXE` installer or a Macintosh `.DMG`... Otherwise like @Oleg said make sure both OS computers have [**AIR runtime**](https://get.adobe.com/air/) installed (you have it on your specific Mac since it comes with AIR SDK) but anyone else using your `.AIR` file needs runtime installed (to avoid separate installs of both app & runtime just export your installer apps with "include captive runtime" option selected)

Answer (score 0):

You're correct that Adobe AIR is cross platform compatible, but publishing from a Mac doesn't give you a Windows-runnable app, nor does publishing from Windows give you a Mac-runnable app.

You'll need to compile on a PC to get a Windows-runnable .exe

Comment: That's not true. Not sure about Windows version of Adobe Animate, but Mac OS one does provide you a possibility to build Windows-runnable.exe.

Comment: @OlegKnaus Interesting.  Is that new in the latest version of AIR?  I'm used to building through Flash Builder or using ADT on the command line -- both of which only build a native application for the current platform.